# WebIOPi patch for Raspberry Pi Zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, webiopi

I am looking for a patch of WebIOPi for the Pi Zero W.

I will appreciate you very much, if you could suggest where I can find it on the internet.

WebIOPi's version is 0.7.1.

I could find some patches for the Pi 3 and 2 but I can't find any for the Pi Zero W.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old version installed you will need to run the following:

```
sudo dpkg --purge python2-webiopi
sudo dpkg --purge python3-webiopi
find /usr | grep -i webiopi  | sort > ~/webiopi.old.files
tar cjvf ~/webiopi.old.tbz --files-from ~/webiopi.old.files 
cat ~/webiopi.old.files | sort -r | sed -e 's/^/sudo rm -f /;' |  sh 2>/dev/null
cat ~/webiopi.old.files | sort -r | sed -e 's/^/sudo rmdir /;' | sh 2>/dev/nul
```

Then to install the working version run:

```
git clone https://github.com/thortex/rpi3-webiopi.git
cd rpi3-webiopi
```

You will need to install some Debian package management development files:

```
cd dev
./01_setup-required-packages.sh
```

Then install Python setup tools and and development files:

```
./03_install_python_dev.sh
```

Next run this to build the package:

```
./10_make_deb.sh
```

Finally install WebIOPi+ with:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/build.webiopi/python2-webiopi*.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/build.webiopi/python3-webiopi*.deb
sudo webiopi-select-python 2

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart webiopi
```

To install WebIOPi+ for Python 3 run:

```
webiopi-select-python 3
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart webiopi
```

To to start/stop/restart WebIOPi daemon:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/webiopi restart
```

This WebIOPi+ is based off the original WebIOPi version however it has been designed to work with the Pi Zero.

For more information here is the [official GitHub page](https://github.com/thortex/rpi3-webiopi).

Comment: Hi Darth,

Thank you very much for your quick & adequate response.
I have tried to install all necessary items onto my device.
It is working "more than perfectly".
For your information, the detail of my device is; 
    RasPi Zero W ver. 1.1

I understand you are in UK, and I would like to express my sympathy for the fire of an apartment in London recently.

Thank very much again and I am hoping you will help me on RasPi matter soon.
Tam

Comment: Thank you for your condolences. If my answer has helped you solve your problem I would appreciate it if you mark it as correct.